# How would I put the JS into its own file in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I have some JS in a chtml file in Visual Studio 2013. I just can't seem to figure out how to put it into its own JS file in VS. How do I put the line

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345&sensor=false">
    </script>
```

into its own .js file?

and then how would I put the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Into its own file?
I'm trying to remove them from the html file for clarity

Comment: the script tag with a src IS in it's own file. The function initialize would be cut and pasted out of the script tag and placed in an external file then brought in the same way the google api script is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a new file using `Add > New Item` and choose a JavaScript file (it may be called JScript in the new item dialog.

Call it something like `map.js`, for example.

Then add a script tag, thus:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
```

If you accumulate a few scripts, you may want to use the bundling feature in .NET - but this will work for your small snippet.

Comment: hi let me add more to the original question. If I added the file how would it look in my bundleconfig file? all of the .js files are to locations in my solutions folder (ex. ~/Scripts/..)

Comment: You can bundle it using `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/maps").Include("~/map.js"));` - then add it to the page using the `maps` bundle name, rather than `map.js`.

Comment: You keep the script tag for the Google Maps API, the script tag I have shown in the answer is additional to that. I have shown both in the answer to illustrate this now.